# Asp.Net Core 1.0.0: Writing into appsetting.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'd like to provide connection string during the first run of my app and save it to `appsettings.json` via usual form. I'm able to detect if there is a `ConnectionString` section in the file and if it's correct. How can I save the value provided?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
var config = builder.Build();
config["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"] = "MyConnectionStringHere";

//...    

var setting = config["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]; // also returns "MyConnectionStringHere"
```

For more info on configuration files, and using built-in functionality, check out [Asp.Net Core Configuration](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html)

Comment: @Tseng That's right. I suppose `IConfiguration` doesn't provide the possibility..

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this unless writing to the json file ourselves?